# Отправка XML SOAP

Tags: xml, php, soap

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста. Искал примеры по гуглу, но не нарыл ничего того, что могло бы мне помочь. Поэтому, не могли бы вы мне на пальцах объяснить, как в php методом SOAP отправить например вот эту XML:

```
<xsd:element name="ПРИМЕР!">

</xsd:element>
```

например вот сюда:

```
example.ru.
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь. Башка уже лопается от кучи непонятного кода.

Comment: Буквально вчера [писали об этом на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187390/).

Comment: хм, странно, не отображался этот коммент, когда я писал... видимо пора спать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, таким образом на сервер это не передаётся. Лично я создавал WSDL сервер, который отдавал мне по протоколу SOAP информацию. Но я не знаю когда нужно передать по соап что-то на сервер. Для этого обычно используется API.

Клиент вызывает метод сервера, получает в ответ xml (wsdl).

Answer (score 1):

Буквально вчера на хабре была статься именно по вашему вопросу: [Пишем SOAP клиент-серверное приложение на PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187390/)