# API почты России

Tags: php, soap

(из вопроса [Отправка `XML SOAP`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238795) )

Да я понимаю это. Скажу так - есть доступ к `API` почты россии. Осуществляется с помощью `SOAP`. Т.е. мне нужно отправить `xml` с параметрами `SOAP` запросом на их `SOAP` сервер (Он уже запущен у них, к примеру этот самый example.ru). Вот я и не могу понять - КАК?

Из вопроса: [Отправка XML SOAP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238795)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про SoapClient РНР. А дальше уже:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/end_point.wsdl');
```

и

```
$result = $client->SomeFunction($data);
```